# Returning statement from dynamic query SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I'm writing procedure which take some parameters and send them into dynamic query.

So, my question is - can I return statement from dynamic query like that:

```
 set @sql='
    if not exists (
        select * 
        from sys.columns 
        where object_id=OBJECT_ID('''+@table_name+''',''U'') 
            and (name=''path_file''or name=''file_path'')
     )
    begin
      set @msg=''error''
    end'
```

@msg-procedure variable

Comment: I assume this is SQL Server?  In which case look in to using `sp_executesql` and output parameters?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Why do you need dynamic sql here? From what you posted it is not needed at all.

Comment: SeanLange i have parametrs in my proc? like table name,file name,file path and i dont know how to do this witout dynamic cause for example i cant write something like: create table @table_name without dynamic